# Spring boot JPA Hibernate return nested Json Object : Reddit style comment system

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
     private Long id;
     private String content;


     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
        private Comment parentComment;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentComment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Comment> childrenComments = new ArrayList<>(); 
}

public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

}
```

Here is how I am saving replies for a specific comment.

```
Comment parent = new Comment();
        parent.setContent(" 1 comment");
        parent = commentRepository.save(parent);

        Comment reply1 = new Comment();
        reply1.setContent("reply 1 to comment 1");
        reply1.setParentComment(parent);

        Comment reply2 = new Comment();
        reply1.setContent("reply 2 to comment 1");
        reply1.setParentComment(parent);

        parent = commentRepository.save(parent);
```

When I do commentrepository.findAll()

I would like to return the following json data.

```
{

            "id": 1,
            "content": "1 comment",
            "replies" :[
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "content": "reply 1 to comment 1"
                },

                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "content": "reply 2 to comment 1"
                }

                ]
        }
```

My goal is to build a reddit style comment system. Where each comment has an array of comments(replies). When I query for all comments, using spring data jpa, I only want the root comments and their nested replies.

In the above case, don't want something like this:

```
{
    {

        "id": 1,
        "content": "1 comment",
        "replies" :[
            {
                "id": 2,
                "content": "reply 1 to comment 1"
            },

            {
                "id": 3,
                "content": "reply 2 to comment 1"
            }

        ]
    }

    {
        "id": 2,
        "content": "reply 1 to comment 1"
     }

   {
        "id": 2,
        "content": "reply 1 to comment 1"
    }
}
```

I have spent several days on this without success. I have tried using @jsonIgnore and other jackson annotations without success. Any suggestions or recommendations?
Thank you in adavance. you are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jpa method:

```
List<Comment> findByChildrenCommentsIsNull();
```

to get all the root comments and their nested replies.

Comment: thanks for the hint. What I actually wanted is commentRepository.findByParentCommentIsNull();

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

```
List<Comment> comments = commentRepository.findByParentCommentIsNull();
```

Comment: Dont just include the code. Kindly explain how your answer will solve the issue.Try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer